# How to add interval value into UIDatePicker in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I want to know how to add interval value into `UIDateTimePicker` in swift

```
8am-8:30am
8:30am-9am
9am-9:30am
9:30am-10am
10am-10:30am
10:30am-11am
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Add one `UIPickerView` in your `xib` or your `storyboard` `viewController` after that set the `delegate` and `datasoucre` of that `UIPickerView` with your `viewController`. Now create one array of string like this.

```
 var timeArr: [String] = [String]()
```

Now initialize this array in `viewDidLoad` like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.timeArr = ["8:00AM - 8:30AM", "8:30AM - 9:00AM", "9:00AM - 9:30AM", "9:30AM - 10:00AM"]
}
```

Now add the `delegate` and `datasource` method of `UIPicker` in your `ViewController` like this

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
     return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.timeArr.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return self.timeArr[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(self.timeArr[row])
}
```

This will create Picker that you want to select time.

Comment: minuteInterval is only for only dropdown. 8:00AM - 8:30AM < I want like that.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you want. But if you want this type of picker than you can simply create one by just passing this type of array of string to `UIPicker`.

Comment: 8:00AM - 8:30AM
8:30AM - 9:00AM
9:00AM - 9:30AM
9:30AM - 10:00AM

Comment: Yes create one array of string like this and pass that array to `UIPicker`. It will solve your problem